# Nested Lists in Dict : Accessing members of list within the list of a dictionary

Tags: python

```
def index_dir(self, base_path):
    num_files_indexed = 0
    allfiles = os.listdir(base_path)
    self._documents = os.listdir(base_path)
    num_files_indexed = len(allfiles)
    docnumber = 0
    self._inverted_index = collections.defaultdict(list)
    docnumlist = []
    for file in allfiles: 
            self.documents = [base_path+file] #list of all text files
            f = open(base_path+file, 'r')
            lines = f.read()

            tokens = self.tokenize(lines)
            docnumber = docnumber + 1
            for term in tokens:  
            # check if the key/term already exists in the dictionary, 
            # if yes, just add a new key value/term into the dict
                if term not in sorted(self._inverted_index.keys()):
                    newlist=[]
                    tf=1
                    self._inverted_index[term] = []
                    #self._inverted_index[term][docnumber] +=1
                    newlist.append(docnumber)
                    newlist.append(tf)
                    self._inverted_index[term].append(newlist) #appending list to a list  
                else:
                        if docnumber not in self._inverted_index.get(term):
                            newlist=[]
                            tf=1
                            newlist.append(docnumber)
                            newlist.append(tf)
                            self._inverted_index[term].append(newlist) 
            f.close()
    print '\n \n'
    print 'Dictionary contents: \n'
    for term in sorted(self._inverted_index):
        print term, '->', self._inverted_index.get(term)
    return num_files_indexed
    return 0
```

What I get from this code:
dictionary in this format:
term <- [[docnumber, term freq][docnumber, term freq]]
for ex: if the word cat occurs in doc 1.txt for three times and in Doc 3.txt twice:
I get:
cat <- [[1,1],[1,1],[1,1],[3,1][3,1]]
so, instead of getting [1,1] three times, I want [1,3] added to the list
I don't know how to get rid of repetitive members of the list and increment the term freq.

What I should get:
cat <- [[1,3],[3,2]] i.e. thrice in Doc 1 and twice in doc 3. 

I have tried ways to work it out, but I get access errors all the time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just edited your code display, hope thats correct

Comment: Also it would be nice, if you took a relook at your question text section to make it easy for others.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> cat = [[1,1],[1,1],[1,1],[3,1],[3,1]]
>>> [(k,len(list(v))) for k, v in groupby(cat,itemgetter(0))]
[(1, 3), (3, 2)]
```

will fix your code. But that doesn't solve the problem of why the code is doing the wrong thing in the first place! The solution is to use the [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class, which will do the work for you if you just feed it a list of words.

```
>>> words = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit ames, lorem ipsum dolor sit ames.".split(" ")
>>> Counter(words)
Counter({'ipsum': 2, 'sit': 2, 'dolor': 2, 'lorem': 1, 'ames.': 1, 'ames,': 1, 'Lorem': 1})
>>> Counter(map(str.lower, words))
Counter({'ipsum': 2, 'sit': 2, 'dolor': 2, 'lorem': 2, 'ames.': 1, 'ames,': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

final counts:

```
{'cat':[[1,3], [3,2]]}
```

Words in current document:

```
{'cat':3}
```

I like that you have chosen to use defaultdict.
It makes the following possible and is faster then looping through the keys.

```
from collections import defaultdict
    all_word_counts = defaultdict(list)
    all_word_counts['cat'].append([1, 3])
```

First count the word frequency in a given document

```
word_count = defaultdict(int) #reset each document
for term in self.tokenize(lines):
    word_count[term] += 1
```

Before moving on to the next document update the all_word_counts

```
for word, count in word_count.iteritems():
    all_word_counts[word].append([docnumber, count])
```